# How to covert Datetime Format in JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json

Now a Days I get Data using service that is converted to JSON Data format In this Data one field is Date that format is "/Date(1325010600000+0530)/" How I can Convert this Data into Correct DateTime Format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use following for converting datetime format:

```
         var date_sdate = result[i].StartDateTime;
         var ds = new Date(parseInt(/\/Date\((\d+).*/.exec(date_sdate)[1]))
         var sd = ds.format("dd/MM/yyyy");
         alert(sd);
```